# How to resolve NSAppleMusicUsageDescription error

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11

I am currently running my app on my own device. The goal is to play songs saved locally in the Music App. I import MediaPlayer and try executing the following

```
            MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
                if status == .authorized {
                    print("authorized")
                }
            }
```

My Info.plist looks like the following

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to play music</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, whenever I run the app on my device, it instantly crashes and gives me

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please make sure that your app is using this Info.plist file in which you have added this "NSAppleMusicUsageDescription" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are multiple instances of `Info.plist`...I was looking at the one under the directory, the one that was easy to spot.

Instead you need to access the proper plist by going to Project Settings-> Info tab at the top. Add it there.